# c# extract month no values

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, extract

I have troubles wiht geting errors for `[]` and this error `IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)`. Now I put `EXTRACT(MONTH form table)` in this `[]` brackets, now program says no value given for one or more parameter.

Hire is code:

`string queryString = "SELECT sum(skupaj) FROM [cas] where sifra = " + textBox1.Text + " and [EXTRACT(MONTH FROM Datum)] = " + textBox2.Text + "";`

Comment: Please don't create your SQL query by concatting strings together.  It leaves you very vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Use parameterized queries instead.

Comment: I am using parametrized queries, but when I need data form table I don't know how to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, your final query should look like this:

```
SELECT sum(skupaj) 
FROM [cas] where sifra = 123 
and MONTH(Datum) = 4
```